# Adding Item to SharePoint Search index manually

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010, indexing

I am looking for a way to add a document to Search Index using API, as and when document gets added to document library.

I can add eventhandler and write a code to call API. I need to know if API supports such interface. Any sample will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that SharePoint (2007 and 2010) have passive indexing, meaning it is out of your control beyond scheduling the indexing service to run at a certain frequency.  That being the case, there are occasions when your search cache will be out of sync, such as when you first delete an item.  However, I believe you can programmatically prime the index service.

It is also possible to have SharePoint non-SharePoint content, such as a UNC path, via the Central Admin.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am under same impression that we can manually modify the index. In our case Document view is using search API behind the scene. So after uploading a document, user don't see the documents till it get indexed. Do you know of any article or reference that can guide me right direction?

Comment: All the info I am seeing so far says to restart the Search Service, which can be done with .NET Class 'ServiceProcess', but I thought I remembered a programmatic what to do it with the API.  still looking

Comment: Glenn, thanks for trying. Restarting service or initiate incremental crawl is an option but too slow. I am hoping to use API to get as close to realtime as possible.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to manually add or update index items.  You might be able to fake that by writing your own content provider for search but a.) that's a lot of work b.) that probably won't play well with the out of the box providers for SharePoint...considering that you are probably trying to index SharePoint content and c.) you still have to wait for a crawl to come along and call your content provider to update the index.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned it isn't quite possible to do what you want.  However you can decrease the latency between when you add content and when it gets indexed.  The process looks like this:

1. Create a new Search Content Source that includes your data that needs to be rapidly searched
2. Add only sites that you care about rapid search to this content source
3. Schedule this content source's incremental crawl to happen really often. Consider programmatically watching the crawl status so that you could restart the crawl after it has completed.
4. Tune your search databases I/O and its indexes so that search crawling happens as fast as possible.